# where in the memory of PS block of Zynq the captured image data is stored of Zynq Processor ? So that I can take it to PL block using AXI interface

Tags: linux, fpga, gige-sdk, zynq

I have a GigE camera. I am using Zynq board. Now using linux programming I program the PS part of Zynq processor and capture the video and Now I have imagebuffer variable which has the captured Image data. I want to take the data from PS to PL part using the AXI interface I am probably going to use the AXI_VDMA interconnect, the problem is where in the memory the Imagebuffer is stored so that I can bring it to the PL part in Zynq.

Here is the image of Zynq processor.
[image]

Comment: The answer depends to some extent on how your application is structured. Is there a user-space application memory mapping the video frame buffer?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the CPU accesses the video image buffer using either a kernel or user space virtual address. The progammable logic uses physical addresses, so you will need to translate the virtual address to a physical address and configure AXI_VDMA to use that.

In there Linux kernel there is a device driver for xilinx_axi_vdma which uses dma-mapping to solve the virtual/physical mapping problem.

See [XAPP792:](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp792-high-performance-video-zynq.pdf) and its corresponding reference design for more details on how to use this.